# Change default User-Agent in WebView UWP

Tags: c#, webview, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp

I need set custom UA and I use

```
httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "blahblah");
theWebView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(httpRequestMessage);
```

But if I click any link on page this UA erased and set default UA.

I found same question
[WebView - Define User-Agent on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856266/webview-define-user-agent-on-every-request) but maybe it fixed in 1607?

Comment: Here's a killer trick: https://gist.github.com/mattdot/3b53af7756c061e06f60623c766f657a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WebView is not a general-purpose browser, it does have some "limitations" that are not currently supported. There is no API that can set the default User-Agent that's used in every request. As a workaround we can use [WebView.NavigationStarting event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting.aspx) along with [WebView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatewithhttprequestmessage.aspx) to set User-Agent in every request.

For more information about how to do this, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39208922/5506161). The key point here is removing handler for `NavigationStarting` event and cancelling navigation in the original request and then adding the handler after `NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage` to make sure `NavigationStarting` event can capture next requests like following:

```
WebView wb = new WebView();
wb.NavigationStarting += Wb_NavigationStarting;
...
private void NavigateWithHeader(Uri uri)
{
    var requestMsg = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
    requestMsg.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "blahblah");
    wb.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(requestMsg);

    wb.NavigationStarting += Wb_NavigationStarting;
}

private void Wb_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    wb.NavigationStarting -= Wb_NavigationStarting;
    args.Cancel = true;
    NavigateWithHeader(args.Uri);
}
```